# Request body empty even with body parser

Tags: node.js, express

req.body is empty. I tried req.query but it's empty too.

I looked up all similar question but none solve my problem.

I am using body parser too.

Html-

```html
<form id="signup" action='/users/signup' method='post'>
        <div>Email:<input name="email" type="email"/></div>
    <div>Password:<input name="password1" type="password"/></div>
    <div>Enter Password again:<input name="password2" type="password"/></div>
    <div><button type='submit' id='signupbtn' class='formbtn'>Submit</button></div>
    <a href='' id='showlogin'>Already have an account? Log in here</a>
</form>
```

Server.js-

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('../public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/',require(__dirname+'/routes/login.js').router);
app.use('/',require(__dirname+'/routes/signup.js').router);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});


app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log('Server running on port'+PORT);
});
```

Signup.js-

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();


router.post('/users/signup',function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
});

exports.router=router;
```

Comment: ```router.post('users/signup',function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
});``` Try with this

Comment: I don't find any issue with the program.. I just tested it and it was working... Check the git repo here https://github.com/Skillnter/Stackoverflow-q1 .. just updated sendFile for sending HTML file...

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi not able to connect to server

Comment: @HimanshuBansal not working for me :(

Comment: I can confirm that your code works fine. I can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!!.

I was using preventDefault on submit button to keep the page from reloading but it also prevented data from being sent to the server.

Comment: How `preventDefault` was blocking your data and not the `api` call?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal it is like <form post='/users/login'> and inside the form there is a submit button on which I had put preventDefault() using addEventListener JavaScript. The form was posting to '/users/login' but the preventDefault prevented the inputs to go inside req.body.

Comment: Well I checked and having `preventDefault()` on submit isn't blocking the form data in the req.body.... most probably you might have something wrong in the Request that you were making to APIs..... Because `action='/users/signup'` won't work if you are using `preventDefault`..